# Not Sure How to Proceed

Tags: windows, copy, command, xcopy

I am running a NVR on my pc and I create a folder everyday with the date as the folder name like so...(013124) C:/user/profile/videos/013124. At 1202AM I Copy this folder to a network share for backup.

I want to write a batch file to copy all content of my videos directory to the backup share except for the current days recording.

This is what I currently use...

```
xcopy C:\Users\profile\Videos\Recordings\01302024\* R:\Recordings\01302024\*  /I /F /E /C /Y
```

I would like to know is there a way to write a batchfile to pull in today's date automatically as the exclusion?
Copy all content except for what was created on today's date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.